# Why is my array looping out of bounds?

Tags: java, arrays

Code starts here:

```
 System.out.print("Please enter number of rows: ");

  rows = keyboard.nextInt();  

      while(rows > MAX_ROWS || 0 > rows){
          System.out.print("ERROR: Out of range, try again: ");

          rows = keyboard.nextInt();


      }

      rowsTotal = new double[rows];
      positions = new double [rows][];

      for(index = 0; index < rowsTotal.length; index++){
          System.out.print("Please enter number of positions in row " + (char)(index+65) + " : ");
          pos = keyboard.nextInt();
          if(pos > MAX_POSITIONS){
              System.out.print("ERROR: Out of range, try again: ");
              pos = keyboard.nextInt();
          }
          positions[index] = new double[pos];


          }

      while(input != 'X'){    
      System.out.print("(A)dd, (R)emove, (P)rint,          e(X)it : ");

      input = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
      input = Character.toUpperCase(input);




      if(input == 'P'){
          for(int index1= 0; index1 < rowsTotal.length; index1++){
              System.out.print((char)(index1+65) + ":   " );

              for(int pos1= 0; pos1 < pos; pos1++){

                  **System.out.print(positions[index1][pos] + "  ");** 
              }
              System.out.print("[   " + totals + ", " + "   " + averages + "]");
              System.out.println();



      }

      }
```

**Error Message as Below:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
at xxxxx.main(xxxxx.java:75)
```

which is this line of code `System.out.print(positions[index1][pos] + "  ");`

Comment: Should it be `System.out.print(positions[index1][pos1] + "  ");`? (`pos1` instead of `pos`)?

Comment: What is your code intended to do?

Comment: tried, that didn't work. same error.

Comment: I guess you did meant to read element [pos1], not [pos]. If pos is the number of elements in that array (according to your loop it is), than there is, of course, never an element with that index... [Edit]: I'.... typing... to.... slow... :D

Comment: my code is intended to create a 2d of size [rows][positions(pos)]

Comment: @Johannes, so do I need to create a new array of size pos1? where would I place the array initialization?

Comment: If I got that right, you're reading "pos" directly from the user's input. Have you verified that pos actually IS inside the array's bounds?

Comment: if(pos > MAX_POSITIONS){System.out.print("ERROR: Out of range, try again: ");
     pos = keyboard.nextInt();

Comment: Yeah, forget about my complaint, missed the line where you are actually creating the arrays. Instead, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is simple once you read the whole code.
a) It needs to be `System.out.print(positions[index1][pos1] + "  ");`
b) "pos" is the size of the LAST array inside the positions array. BUt not all of them have the same size. So if earlier arrays are smaller (for example if you entered 1,2,3), than the earlier arrays run out of bounds. You have to loop pos1 to positions[index1].length (so change line 73 to `for(int pos1= 0; pos1 < positions[index1].length; pos1++)`)